# Leave only one String from multiple Strings - Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to leave only one String from an Array:

```
var string = "dog";

var array = ["dog","cat","bird","snake","tiger","dog", "dog", "cat"];
```

Well it looks stupid why I have written "dog" multiple times, but this is only an example.

In real it would make a array from a input-tag. Like this:

```
  firstEntry = true;

  inputValue = inputfield.value;

  if(inputValue != ''){
      if(firstEntry){
      inputArray.push(inputValue);
      firstEntry = false;
  }

//And know it should leave only one String

  inputValueSplit = inputValue.split(/ /g);
  removeFromArray(inputValueSplit,'');//This is a external function, (deletes empty Strings)
  inputArray = inputValueSplit;


  inputArray.filter(inputValue); // Here it should leave only one 
                                 // String of multiple Strings from
                                 // same value.
```

I didn't find anything here or in Google..

Comment: It's very unclear what you try to achieve. You just want to filter out the array so that only the single value you are looking for is left?

Comment: *I didn't find anything here or in Google..* - if i understood correctly [google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+to+filter+an+array+using+javascript+to+remove+duplicates+javascript&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&ei=HhWwU7aJFcTM8gfV6YAY&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: Please try to rephrase the question to make more clear what you are looking for.

Comment: Basically, if there are N occurrences of a particular value, you want to keep at most one?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean. If you need an array containing only 'dog'-values from the initial array, you can use `Array.filter`:

```
var dogs = ["dog","cat","bird","snake","tiger","dog", "dog", "cat"]
            .filter( function(a){ return a == this; }, 'dog' );
//=> ['dog','dog','dog']
```

if you want to remove double 'dog'-values from the initial array:

```
var singleout = 'dog'
   ,dogs = (["dog","cat","bird","snake","tiger","dog", "dog", "cat"]
            .filter( function(a){ return a != this }, singleout ));
// now dogs contains no 'dog' value, so add 'dog' to it again
dogs.push(singleout);
//=> ["cat", "bird", "snake", "tiger", "cat", "dog"]
```

Not using `filter`, this is a generic method to remove double values from an array:

```
function noDoubles(arr) {
  var doubleChk = {}, noDoubles = []; 
  for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i+=1) { doubleChk[arr[i]] = true; }
  for (var l in doubleChk) { noDoubles.push(l); }
  return noDoubles;
}
noDoubles(["dog","cat","bird","snake","tiger","dog", "dog", "cat"]);
//=> ["dog", "cat", "bird", "snake", "tiger"]
```

Finally, having learned from the previous function and using `Array.filter`, removing doubles from an `Array` can be as simple as:

```
function noDoubles(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(val) {
     return !this[val] ? ((this[val] = true), true) : false;
    }, {} );    
 }
noDoubles(["dog","cat","bird","snake","tiger","dog", "dog", "cat"]);
//=> ["dog", "cat", "bird", "snake", "tiger"]
```

See [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for the `Array.filter` method. The linked page also contains a shim to enable the method in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function; if a particular value was found before it will be filtered from then onwards:

```
var string = "dog";
var array = ["dog","cat","bird","snake","tiger","dog", "dog", "cat"];

var result = (function() {
    var found = false;

    // @see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
    return array.filter(function(value) {
        if (value == string) {
            // only allow this one time
            return found ? false : found = true;
        }
        return true;
    });
}());
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/werezefa/1/watch?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

Well I thought if I have:

```
array = ["dog","cat","bird","snake","tiger","dog", "dog", "cat"]
```

I wish I could have:

```
array = ["dog","cat","bird","snake","tiger"]
```

And thanks to [Kooilnc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58186/kooiinc) for the ***noDouble***-function.

It was the perfect way I needed.